# Chart creation on sugarCRM community edition 6.5

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am trying to create a pie chart on my SugarCRM dashboard.
I was following the link but not getting the pie chart drawn on the dashboard.

I am able to see the title (label) of the chart on the add dashlet popup but when I am adding the same there is nothing getting add on my dashboard.